# while loop is ending to early in SAP Hana Sql Procedure

Tags: while-loop, procedure, sql-scripts, hana-sql-script

I have the following SQL-Script:

```
PROCEDURE "P_OVERVIEW" ()
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
READS SQL DATA
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE I INT = 0;
  WHILE :I < 24 DO
    SELECT A, B, COUNT(A) AS COUNT, LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -:I)) AS "DATE", I
    FROM Table
    WHERE LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -:I)) BETWEEN ENTRY_DATE AND VALID_UNTIL
    GROUP BY A, B
    ORDER BY B, A;
    I := I+1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

I am using it in an .hdbprocedure-File on SAP Cloud Platform. Deploying is working fine.
When I call the procedure with `CALL P_OVERVIEW()` I am just getting the values when `I = 0`. Any Idea wy this happend?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo in the code.
When referencing the value of a varible, `I` you have to put a colon `:` in front: `:I`.

The following should work

```
PROCEDURE "P_OVERVIEW" ()
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
READS SQL DATA
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE I INT = 0;
  WHILE :I < 24 DO
    SELECT A, B, COUNT(A) AS COUNT, LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -:I)) AS "DATE", I
    FROM Table
    WHERE LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -:I)) BETWEEN ENTRY_DATE AND VALID_UNTIL
    GROUP BY A, B
    ORDER BY B, A;
    I := :I+1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

As a remark: using a loop here is probably not the best approach. 
You could just create a subquery, that generates the "last day of the month" for the past two years on the fly.
The `SERIES_GENERATE_` generator table function is an easy option for that.